# How to check if a button was pressed

Tags: c++, winapi, button

My goal is to populate the client area of my window with a bunch of different child controls. Things like buttons check boxes and static text but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to catch the button clicked message.

My Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include "resource.h"

HMENU        BUTTON1;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT wParam, LONG lParam) ;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
     {
     static char szAppName[] = "Keyboarding" ;
     HWND        hwnd;
     MSG         msg;   
     WNDCLASS    wndclass; 
     HMENU       hMenu;


     hMenu = LoadMenu(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));

     if (!hPrevInstance)
          {
          wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
          wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
          wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
          wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
          wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
          wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
          wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
          wndclass.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH));
          wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
          wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

          RegisterClass (&wndclass) ;
      }

     hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,         // window class name
                    "Lab 6",   // window caption
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,     // window style
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x position
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y position
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,                // hmmmmm???
                    NULL,                    // parent window handle
                    hMenu,                    // window menu handle
                    hInstance,               // program instance handle
                  NULL) ;              // creation parameters

     HWND button1 = CreateWindow( WC_BUTTON, 
                         "Push Button", 
                         WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                         50, 
                         50, 
                         100, 
                         24, 
                         hwnd, 
                         BUTTON1, 
                         hInstance,
                         NULL);

     HWND button2 = CreateWindow( WC_BUTTON, 
                         "Auto Check Button?", 
                         WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                         50, 
                         50, 
                         100, 
                         24, 
                         hwnd, 
                         NULL, 
                         hInstance,
                         NULL);

     HWND button3 = CreateWindow( WC_BUTTON, 
                         "Push Button", 
                         WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                         50, 
                         50, 
                         100, 
                         24, 
                         hwnd, 
                         NULL, 
                         hInstance,
                         NULL);

     HWND editControl = CreateWindow( WC_BUTTON, 
                         "Push Button", 
                         WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                         50, 
                         50, 
                         100, 
                         24, 
                         hwnd, 
                         NULL, 
                         hInstance,
                         NULL);

     HWND StaticControl = CreateWindow( WC_STATIC, 
                         "Hello World", 
                         WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                         50, 
                         100, 
                         100, 
                         24, 
                         hwnd, 
                         NULL, 
                         hInstance,
                         NULL);

     HWND ListBox = CreateWindow( WC_BUTTON, 
                         "Push Button", 
                         WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                         50, 
                         50, 
                         100, 
                         24, 
                         hwnd, 
                         NULL, 
                         hInstance,
                         NULL);

     ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow) ;
     UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

     while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
          {
            TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
            DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
          }
     return (int) msg.wParam ;
     }

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT wParam,
                            LONG lParam)
     {
     HDC         hdc ;
     PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
     TEXTMETRIC  tm;
     RECT        rClientRect;
     RECT        rWindowRect;
     SIZE        size;
     int        cButtons = 0;

     switch (message)
          {         

     case WM_COMMAND:
         switch(LOWORD(wParam))
         {
         case BUTTON1:
             break;
         }      

          case WM_PAINT:
                hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;

                EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
                return 0 ;

          case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage (0) ;
                return 0 ;
          }

     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
     }
```

I'm trying to catch my first button labaled button1 and has the "ID" BUTTON1. I have tried just catching them in my WM_COMMAND and it says my BUTTON1 is unidentified.

Comment: I tried catching my BUTTON1 in my WM_COMMAND and switching the LOWORD of the wParam. It just says BUTTON1 isn't identified.

Comment: @JesseMoreland, It's in `WinMain`. Your procedure can't see it.

Comment: I have to make a procedure for child controls?

Comment: No, you should either create all the buttons in your window procedure, catching WM_CREATE, or declare them globally/statically, although I'd recommend the second. Also, you don't appear to be specifying an ID for any of your buttons, so you won't be able to catch this

Comment: I did create an ID for my first button becuase i'm trying to learn.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that... But yeah, you need to declare your buttons somewhere else so the procedure can see it, as shown in the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
         case BUTTON1: {
```

But before it will recognize BUTTON1 you will have to declare it in such a way that it can be recognized by the message handler: for example make it a global variable, instead of declaring it in the WinMain:

```
HMENU       BUTTON1;

int WINAPI WinMaietcetc..
```

Let me know if this works !

Comment: It worked kind of. It says BUTTON1 needs to be a modifiable expression. Updating code now.

Comment: You need to give BUTTON1 a value, so `HMENU BUTTON1 = 5`. You'd be better of using a define (`#define BUTTON1 5`) or a `const int` instead of just a HMENU

Comment: Because it's a switch, I think it has to be const or defined in order for it to be allowed by the compiler

Comment: That didn't fix anything either. Very frustrating :(

Comment: Thanks you guys for helping!

@RT_34, I haven't actulaly changing anything. I tampered with the defines and stuff but it says CreateWindow doesn't except an int in the HMENU spot.

Comment: You need to cast it to HMENU, so in the ID slot, type `(HMENU)BUTTON1`

Comment: I got it guys. The #define of the button worked but I needed to make it (HMENU) BUTTON1 inside of my create window for the button. Thank you everyone! =).